# Different predictions in Keras with the same input and same weights but different batch sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I was trying to optimize my Code when I encountered this strange behaviour with the following model in Keras:

```
# random_minibatches of form (state, action, reward, state_next, done)
random_minibatch = random.sample(list_of_samples, batch_size)

# A state is a list in the form of [x, y]
next_states = [temp[3] for temp in random_minibatch]
# Reshape the next_states for the model
next_states = np.reshape(next_states, [-1, 2])
next_states_preds = model.predict(next_states)

for i, (_, _, _, state_next, _) in enumerate(random_minibatch):
    state_next= np.reshape(state_next, [1, 2])
    pred = model.predict(state_next)

    print("inputs: {} ; {}".format(next_states[i], state_next))
    print(pred)
    print(next_states_preds[i])
    print("amax: {} ; {}".format(np.amax(pred), np.amax(next_states_preds[i])))
    print()
```

and a simple model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation="relu", input_dim=2))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(8))

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.00025))
```

`next_states` is a list of lists in the form of `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]`
and `state_next` is a list in the form of [x, y]

As you can see, `next_states` contains every `state_next` in the for-loop and the input for my model is the same. The only difference is that in the first time I put the whole list of lists in the model and the second time I put the lists in one by one.

My Problem is that I get different outputs from the same input.
An example of the printed output would be:

> inputs: [39 -7] ; [39 -7]
>   [0.    0.   0.    0.   0.   5.457102    0.   0.]
>   [[0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    5.4571013   0.    0.]]
>   amax: 5.457101345062256 ; 5.457101821899414

So at this point I'm not sure if I misunderstood something or just did something wrong somewhere? I would be very glad if someone could help me with that strange behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Not really @NicolasGervais as the model input is the same and there's no operation modifying the output

Comment: Irrelevant to your reported issue, but a final dense layer with `relu` activation does not make any sense from a modeling perspective.

Comment: yeah, you're right @desertnaut.. just a copy paste error

Comment: If so, please correct it

Comment: Sorry, is fixed now